# How to tell Timber which log call is for which Tree?

Tags: android, timber-android

I have Timber library for logging and cooperation with crash-reporting services and I have both Crashlytics and Loggly services in my app.

Thus, I had to plant two trees:

```
Timber.plant(new CrashlyticsTree());
Timber.plant(new LogglyTree(BuildConfig.LOGGLY_TOKEN));
```

Now, each time I call:

```
Timber.e("bla bla");
```

I get all the logs in Loggly, but I want some of them to go to Loggly and some of them to go to Crashlytics, so how do I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out every call to `.e` or `.w` for example, iterates through all planted trees and calls their respective `.e` and `.w` implementations.

This means that if I wanted to separate Library A and Library B I needed to use different logging priority for each.

So I chose to use `.e` for Library A and `.w` for Library B.

In order to do that, I had to create custom trees that inherit from Timber.HollowTree and only implement the needed log call, and leave the rest of them hollow.

```
public class LibraryATree extends Timber.HollowTree {
    @Override
    public void e(Args){
        // Do something
    }
}

public class LibraryBTree extends Timber.HollowTree {
    @Override
    public void w(Args){
        // Do something
    }
}

Timber.plant(new LibraryATree())
Timber.plant(new LibraryBTree())
```

Now in my code, if I want to log something via LibraryA, I do this:

```
Timber.e("Test Library A"); // calls LibraryA's Tree's `.e` method
```

and if I wanted to use Library B's logging utilities I do this:

```
Timber.w("Test Library B"); // calls LibraryB's Tree's `.w` method
```